# How to set property from the inside not using setter

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object property set like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "currentPath", {
    get: function () {
        // some logic here
        return this.currentPath.length === 0;
    }.bind(this),
    set: function(value) {
        // some logic here
        this.currentPath = value;
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Outside of the object I want everybody to access `currentPath` property using getter and setter, like this `navigator.currentPath`, but inside the object I want to set this property by-passing the setter. Is my only option to have two properties - one accessed by others through getter, and another set internally?

Comment: AFAIK, you will need to use 2 properties.... the internal property can be a local variable so that other won't access it

Comment: `this.currentPath = value;` in the setter will be recursive anyway, so you’re going to have to have at least another property or variable. Properties with getters and setters can’t back themselves.

Comment: thanks guys, that's what I thought, just wanted to confirm my guess

Comment: @ArunPJohny, thanks for the example, So basically getter/setter are mostly used for public properties?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a2jmL3db/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to store the property's actual value in the object's prototype (which must be created along with the object itself), while keeping getters and setters to expose the prototype's own property to the outside.

```js
var obj =
    Object.create(
        { currentPath: "" },
        {
            currentPath:
            {
                get: function () {
                    return this.__proto__.currentPath;
                },
                set: function (currentPath) {
                    this.__proto__.currentPath = currentPath;
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Here `obj.currentPath` will invoke the getter or setter, while `obj.__proto__.currentPath` will access the value property directly.

Rather than using `this.__proto__.currentPath` to access the property internally, it is possible to change the call context as appropriate:

```
function logPath()
{
    console.log(this.currentPath);
}

this.logPath(); // use getter
logPath.call(this.__proto__); // don't use getter
// .bind is also an option...
```

Of course, both the object and the prototype are accessible everywhere in code, but depending on the use case, this might be an acceptable or even desirable behavior (just use the prototype where the getter/setter overhead is not needed).

Comment: thanks, interesting solution. But AFAIK, `_proto_` property is not supoorted across all browsers, but this solution seems  to require this property to be supported.

Comment: @Maximus Well, `__proto__` (with 2 underscores on the left and 2 underscores on the right) [is supported by all browsers as of today](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) and it's specified by ES6. You could also use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead. Just be careful with `Object.setPrototypeOf`, which doesn't work in Safari.